# Get RGB value from screen pixels with python

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, rgb, pixel

To get the RGB values from a pixel of the **screen** with coordinates (x,y) in Python, I do:

```
import PIL.ImageGrab
rgb = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[x,y]
```

It was working as I expected until I did:

```
rgb = PIL.ImageGrab.grab().load()[1673,0]
```

Instead of the RGB values of the pixel, I received:

```
IndexError: image index out of range
```

I don't understand why because my screen has 1920x1080 resolution.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do:

```
import PIL.ImageGrab
PIL.ImageGrab.grab().size
```

You will see the resolution that python is detecting in your system. If you are using Windows, you have to go to Screen Configuration and then change: **text, aplications and another elements size** to 100%.

If your resolution is 1920x1080 ,as you said, this should fix the problem.

Comment: Great solution :)

Answer (score 0):

you should use the pyscreeze module

```
import pyscreeze
#the value of pixel whose value is to be get
x=23
y=23

#screen object
screen=pyscreeze.screenshot()

rgb_values=screen.getpixel((x,y))
```