# Get the RGB value of a specific pixel live

Tags: python

How would I be able to get the RGB value of a pixel on my screen live with python? I have tried using

```
from PIL import ImageGrab as ig
while(True):
    screen = ig.grab() 
    g = (screen.getpixel((358, 402))) 
    print(g)
```

to get the value but there is noticeable lag.

Is there another way to do this without screen capturing? Because I think this is the cause of lag.
Is there a way to drastically speed up this process?

is it possible to constrain the ig.grab() to 358, 402 and get the values from there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get RGB value from screen pixels with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636933/get-rgb-value-from-screen-pixels-with-python)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably find it faster to use [mss](https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/index.html), which is specifically designed to provide high speed screenshot capabilities in Python, and can be used like so:

```
import mss

with mss.mss() as sct:
    pic = sct.grab({'mon':1, 'top':358, 'left':402, 'width':1, 'height':1})
    g = pic.pixel(0,0)
```

See the mss documentation for more information. The most important thing is that you want to avoid repeatedly doing `with mss.mss() as sct` but rather re-use a single object.

Comment: How would you incorporate this so it provides live data on the RGB value of the pixel? I edited my question so mine outputs the RBG value constantly, how would you do it with this?

Comment: @JimboNuggets: Add a loop, and likely some kind of sleep call to stop it completely hogging the processor.

Answer (score 0):

The following change will speed up it by 15%

```
pixel = (358, 402)
pixel_boundary = (pixel + (pixel[0]+1, pixel[1]+1))
g = ig.grab(pixel_boundary)
return g.getpixel((0,0))
```

**Runtime:**

- proposed: 383 ms ± 5.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
- original: 450 ms ± 5.31 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)