# Is there a way to capture an image of the screen in python with ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

I want to have python save an image file of the whole screen as a variable with ctypes so that I could access the screen in a program and do something with it (like put it on a pygame window). I can't use any other libraries unless they are included with python (no installing or pip). Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit: I'm using windows 10.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to work with console in python?

Comment: I think this is platform specific and it would help if you told us what OS you are running.

Comment: No, I'm using a .py file

Comment: Also, I'm using windows 10

Comment: Do you want to work with graphic or console?

Comment: I guess graphics, because I want to test it by displaying the screen on a pygame window.

Comment: I think he wants to read pixel values, so it doesn't really matter

Comment: Sorry if my question is hard to understand, I'm fairly new to python and don't know what some things are called.

Comment: Do you want to A: Make a screen reader for blind people that reads the screen B: read pixel values on the screen (Colours)

Comment: Read pixel values

Comment: I know a Mac-only solution, sorry

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636933/get-rgb-value-from-screen-pixels-with-python/42638275) can get you started. (it uses [this](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageGrab.html))

Comment: I can't use any libraries that aren't included with python.

Comment: A) `pygame` is not included with python, B) your question is too broad, I suggest that you limit your question to: "Can I read pixel values of  window in `pygame`?"

Comment: I thought pygame was included with python. Also, I just need to read pixel values. Sending the screen to a pygame window was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PIL.ImageGrab](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageGrab.html) is from PILLOW (a python image library fork which you can install with pip). You can give a bounding box or capture the entire screen.

**Update:** OP now mentions he can't use external libraries.

Then you could [virtually hit printscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/how-to-generate-keyboard-events-in-python) and [read the clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101128/how-do-i-read-text-from-the-windows-clipboard-from-python). The code of PILLOW is open-source feel free to use it.

Remember that you can always [call a command from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python):

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("pip install pillow")
```

Or download the zip of the library and import it in your code.

Comment: I can't use pip. I'm using a school laptop to do this, and the command prompt is blocked.

Comment: I will try that.

Comment: My school doesn't have pip installed. I'll have to try virtually hitting printscreen. I made my own library for controlling the mouse and keyboard, so that is possible for me.

Comment: Manually hitting printscreen doesn't seem to work with my clipboard. I think it copies the picture, but won't paste it in file explorer. It seems to just clear my clipboard.

Comment: pip is installed with Python usually try `python -m pip install pillow`. For the clipboard, try pasting it in paint.

Comment: Well I don't have admin so it gets denied access.

Comment: It does paste in paint

Comment: I'll make a new question for that

Comment: That won't work, every time I hit printscreen it saves it to my onedrive

Comment: I turned that off, maybe I can try hitting printscreen now.