# How to find the RBG color of a certain pixel on the screen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pixel

I have some python code, and I want it to be able to use the pixels on the screen to know what to do using the color of the pixel. Is there any way to print the rbg or get the rbg data for a pixel? — like maybe:

```
red = {255, 0, 0}
pixel = (stuff)
if pixel == red:
    stuff here
```

Comment: Take a look at `PIL`, a python image library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get RGB value from screen pixels with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636933/get-rgb-value-from-screen-pixels-with-python)